# Question on sheaves

Tags: sheaf-theory

Can someone explain the object in point 2, (in the second answer) to this thread

[Failure of isomorphisms on stalks to arise from an isomorphism of sheaves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43314/failure-of-isomorphisms-on-stalks-to-arise-from-an-isomorphism-of-sheaves)

in some more details. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A section of that sheaf over an open set $ U $ is a finite subset of U and a choice of integer for each element in that set. This clearly isn't the constant sheaf but clearly has stalk $\mathbb { Z} $ at every point.

Comment: What is the object after dirct sum? how does it act on a open set?